# Поиск нескольких строк текста в файле

Tags: python, строки, python-2.x, текст

**Имеется:**

Текстовый файл test.txt:

```
   1
   2
   3
   5 - НЕ ТА СТРОКА
   4
   D
   6
   5 - НУЖНАЯ СТРОКА
   6
   7
   5
```

Код:

```
word = str(raw_input("Введите букву:\n"))
num = str(raw_input("Введите цифру:\n"))  
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
     data = file.readlines()
     for line in data:
          if word in line:
               print(line)
               for line in data: 
               # понимаю, что эта строка некорректная,        
               # так как цикл проходит с самого начала файла.
               # Целью было как-то продолжить поиск по файлу,
               # если совпадение найдено.
                    if num in line:
                         print(line)
                         break
```

**Цель:**

Задаем с клавиатуры значение переменной `word = D`, `num = 5`.
Нужно, чтобы скрипт нашел строку, содержащую букву "D". Если такая строка найдена, нужно найти **строку** с цифрой "5", которая идет ПОСЛЕ "D" и закончить поиск после первого нахождения.

Цифра "5" только в конкретном примере может находиться через строчку от буквы "D". В реальности подобных файлов много и цифра может быть в любой строке.

**Вопрос:**

Чем можно заменить *некорректную* строку в коде и какими способами выполнить необходимый поиск?

Comment: Отформатируйте код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заменой одной строки тут не обойтись.
Тут нужно запоминать в отдельную переменную - была ли уже найдена буква. И в зависимости от этого строить условие.

```
word = str(raw_input("Введите букву:\n"))
num = str(raw_input("Введите цифру:\n"))

word_is_found = False

with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    for line in data:
        if not word_is_found:  
            if word in line:
                print(line)
                word_is_found = True
        else:
            if num in line:
                print(line)
                break
```

Либо есть более универсальное решение, которое легко приспособить к любому количеству элементов, которые нужно искать:

```
word = str(raw_input("Введите букву:\n"))
num = str(raw_input("Введите цифру:\n"))

search_seq = [word, num]
search_idx = 0

with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    
    for line in data:
        search_elem = search_seq[search_idx]
        if search_elem in line:
            print(line)
            search_idx += 1
            if not search_idx < len(search_seq):
                break
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Оба кода работают, но есть вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы при выводе необходимой строки отображалась только она? В моем случае при запуске кода появляется пустая строка, дальше нужная строка, потом снова пустая. Хочется понять, как устранить либо обе пустые строки, либо хотя бы первую? Спасибо.

Comment: Когда вы читаете строку из файла, она читается вместе с символом переноса строки в конце. Чтобы не выводить его на печать, замените всюду print(line) на print(line.rstrip())

Comment: И если ответ вам помог, примите его, нажав галочку слева от него.

Comment: Спасибо! Если имеется дополнительный вопрос, связанный с вашим кодом, но помимо него я ввел новые переменные и функции, нужно создавать новый вопрос? Попытался вставить код сюда, но он некорректно отобразился.

Comment: Лучше создавать новый вопрос в таких случаях

Answer (score 3):

```
t = \
'''1
2
3
5
4
D
6
5
6
7
5
'''

w = 'D'
n = '5'

def search(d, n, w):
    return d.index(n, d.index(w)) + 1

data = tuple(map(str.rstrip, open('test.txt').readlines()))

try:
    print(('Номер искомой строки: {}').format(search(data, n, w)))
    #-> Номер искомой строки: 8
    print(('Номер искомой строки: {}').format(search(t.split(), n, w)))  
    #-> Номер искомой строки: 8
except ValueError:
    print('Не найдено!')  # или своя логика обработки
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, что сразу не указал версию Python.Благодарю за ответ. Но в данном случае код отработает только в той ситуации, если цифра "5" будет находиться на следующей строке после "D", верно?

Comment: @47inc, нет, в любой строке.

Comment: Попробовал выполнить код - скрипт выдал номер строки 11, что соответсвует последней цифре "5" в приведенном текстовом файле.

Comment: Скрипт работает правильно, добавил тест.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
text = np.loadtxt("000.txt", dtype="str") # ['1' '2' '3' '5' '4' 'D' '6' '5' '6' '7' '5']
idx = np.where(text=="D")[0][0] + np.where(text[np.where(text=="D")[0][0]:]=="5")[0][0]
print(idx) # 7
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]